# OpenCV Python - Contour - Assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm just trying to find contours in an image using the code [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started).

The code is literally copied from the example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

But the program fails on `findContours` every time.

The error is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_contours.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR && _contours.channels() == 2 && _contours.depth() == CV_32S) in findContours, file /home/shahzeb/Downloads/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1708
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "edges.py", line 7, in <module>
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.error: /home/shahchip/Downloads/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1708: error: (-215) _contours.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_VECTOR && _contours.channels() == 2 && _contours.depth() == CV_32S in function findContours
```

Can someone shed some light on this error. I can't seem to understand any of it.

I did compile OpenCV from source if that's relevant.

EDIT:

For others that are having this error, I found that OpenCV breaks after commit: 6f2fea7ea5f3f61cee860168700537165f3a77db on the master branch of OpenCV.

Comment: I got the same issue. Are you using OpenCV 3.0? I switch back to 2.4.9 and see no problem.

Comment: Yeah, 3.0. The problem is that I use Python3 for everything. But good to know that it's not just me.

Comment: ^^ opencv3.0, not python3.0

Comment: OpenCV 2.* only has bindings for Python 2.

Comment: Yes just try a legacy version of Open CV. Also some examples that you may find have been written with old versions of CV, so they may require some changes to get them to work. Good luck

Comment: Since I do not have an account with 50+ rep, I could not comment on your question, but here is a pull request with a bug fix: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3006